# Delete duplicate rows without altering serial number

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with duplicate rows except serial number column. I want to delete those rows, but have to maintain the serial number ordering.

What I did was I deleted the rows (by using delete command with select) and then removed the serial number column (CID) in the tables property section and again add the column.

This solved the problem but definitely there should be some query to update the serial numbering.

The query I used:

```
delete from ccdoc
where exists (
        select 'x'
        from ccdoc i
        where i.ref=ccdoc.ref and i.cid < ccdoc.cid);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "update the serial numbering"? Is `cid` indeed of type `serial` or are you maintaining your own sequence somehow? Does `cid`have some meaning, other than the ordering? Please edit your question to include the definition of table `ccdoc`. The solution may be a window function, but then you should provide details of the table and how you want to assign `cid` values to rows.

Comment: "*but have to maintain the serial number ordering*" - what exactly should _that_ mean? Rows are not "ordered" in any way.

Comment: I suspect this is an attempt to retain gapless ordering. E.g. if you have `(1,x), (2,y), (3,z)` and delete `(2,y)` I think they want to renumber to `(1,x), (2,z)`. It's pretty hard to tell from the description.

Comment: @CraigRinger: ya.. u r right.. i want to renumber the column.

Comment: @  a_horse_with_no_name : actually i'm trying to import a table ,which is not ordered in any form , and i'm creating another table with this table .  The imported table had many repeated rows which i was totally unaware of and therefore the newly created table also have this repeated rows. Now i have to delete these rows but have to retain the index number.